# Can't not make a iframe for woocommerce my account page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, iframe

I want to make a iframe for demo1.com/my-account in beta.demo2.com but it said demo1.com refused to connect. so that I added bellow code in demo's config file and it just help me to show the login form but I can't login! it's seems after submit the login form it just reloaded. It got blocked somewhere!
Can you help me with it?

```
header('X-Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.demo2.com');
header('Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.demo2.com');
```

Thank you!

I want to make a iframe for demo1.com/my-account in beta.demo2.com but it said demo1.com refused to connect. so that I added bellow code in demo's config file and it just help me to show the login form but I can't login! it's seems after submit the login form it just reloaded. It got blocked somewhere!
Can you help me with it?

```
header('X-Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.demo2.com');
header('Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.demo2.com');
```

Comment: What do you see in your browser console log and the devtools network tab? Please [edit] your question.